# Marriage in Islam without the father of the groom

Tags: nikah

Slms.
I wish to get married to a girl. The girls family approves of me and my family approves of her. However my father has cut ties with me upon his second marriage and no matter how I try to fix it he remains fixed on his decision that he and I should have nothing to do with each other.

My question is this: for the proposal, engagement, and wedding is it permissible for me to do it all myself? As in asking for her hand in marriage and representing myself in the Nikkah.

Comment: Are you going to get married or your father? Are you mature or in need of your parents for taking your decisions?

Comment: @Medi1Saif: the OP wrote "I wish to get married to a girl."

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I know I'm just giving a hint. As I can't find a duplicate with the mobile app.